# How to Clean String from hashtag and twiiter username

Tags: php, regex, twitter

How do I clean a string of tweets like the following case

> 2013 Porsche Cayman First Drive # car # news @ watchthis in Your City

i want to clear the hashtag (# car # news) and twitter user name (in this example @ watchthis)

like this :

> 2013 Porsche Cayman First Drive in Your City

using regular experssion (PHP)

thank you

@bimoheryprabowo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:#\s*[\w\d]+|@\s*[\w\d]+)/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Is print like
Porsche Cayman First Drive 
i want like this 
Porsche Cayman First Drive in Your City

Comment: I updated my answer. You always have one space after `#` and after `@`?

Comment: just like this
#hashtag and @tweetname

Comment: ok. My answer will work with your current string (with spaces) and with many others without spaces

Comment: Porsche Cayman First Drive #car #news @watchthis in Your City

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$text='2013 Porsche Cayman First Drive # car # news @ watchthis in Your City';
echo preg_replace('/(@\s([\\d\\w]+))|(#\s([\\d\\w]+))/', ' ', $text);

OR
echo preg_replace('/((@|#)\s)([\\d\\w]+)/', ' ', $text);
```

[Working EG](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uCjB3F)